# How can I deep link to a Glip team?

Tags: deep-linking, ringcentral, glip

I would like to deep link to a Glip team and previously used the URL format used by the Glipped project, however it no longer works. Instead of taking me to the chat specified by the `chatId`, I would get navigated to the latest open chat I have. Is this a bug or is there a new URL for this?

- Format: `https://app.glip.com/r/chat/{chatId}`
- Project: https://github.com/ringcentral/Glipped

**Update:** The Glipped project has now been updated with the link format in the answer below: https://github.com/ringcentral/Glipped/pull/5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the path parameter, use the query string parameter as follows. Here, `groupId` is the same as the `chatId` in the question above.

- `https://app.glip.com/chat/r?groupid={groupId}`